# Unable to build talib 64 bit

Tags: python, sdk, 64-bit

I am trying to build talib for 64 bit Python. I have a 64 bit Python installation (Using Anaconda 64 bit distribution). I installed Microsoft SDK and set the environment to x64 using the following command
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64
but still no success. I have been struggling with this for past 2 days. Please help.

```
Setting SDK environment relative to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1
\.
Targeting Windows 7 x64 Debug


C:\ABC\Python\pkgs\ta-lib\ta-lib-TA_Lib-0.4.7\ta-lib-TA_Lib-0.4.7>C:\Anaconda64\
python.exe setup.py build --compiler msvc
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'talib\common.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'talib.common' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nolo
go /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\includ
e -Ic:\ta-lib\c\include -IC:\Anaconda64\include -IC:\Anaconda64\PC /Tctalib\comm
on.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\talib\common.obj
common.c
C:\Anaconda64\include\pyconfig.h(68) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include fi
le: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

C:\ABC\Python\pkgs\ta-lib\ta-lib-TA_Lib-0.4.7\ta-lib-TA_Lib-0.4.7>
```

Comment: For Python 2.7, use the Windows SDK version 7.0 (not 7.1). Call `SetEnv.Cmd` with options `/Release /x64`, not Debug. Make sure to have build `ta_libc_cdr.lib` for 64 bit Release. Or search for `TA-Lib` at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Thanks a lot cgohlke. Found the package on lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs.

Answer (score 0):

Download TA_Lib-0.4.10-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib).
And use command
pip install TA_Lib-0.4.10-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl